# Read in a text file 1 line at a time and split the words into an Array Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, input

The user selects a text file. I take the file and split 1 line into individual words. I then take an if statement to see if one of the words is equal to the word "the". There is the word "the" in the first line however it's not saying there is.IT IS picking up other "the"s just not the very first one (yes I know this is a mess, but it's what I'm working with at the moment)

```
try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(test));
    //String text = "";
    String line = br.readLine();

    //while (line != null)
    if(line != null) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 20; j++) //loops through first 20 lines {
            if(line != null) {
                //text += line;
                String[] words = line.toLowerCase().split(" ");
                for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){//loops array of split up words
                    if(words[i].equals("the")) {
                        System.out.println("Found T H E");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Didn't find the");
                        System.out.println(words[i]);
                    }
                    line = br.readLine(); 
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("");
            }
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("It's null");
    }
    br.close();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.err.println("Error" + ex);
}
```

Comment: Best to create a valid [mcve] -- a short compilable and runnable program with a short text file posted in y our question that **we** can compile and run unaltered and that demonstrates your problem for us. One other recommendation: use a debugger to see what Strings are actually being tested. Also are you cleaning punctuation?

Answer (score 2):

Try moving the line

```
line = br.readLine();
```

outside of the loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
```